# How to set requires_grad_ to false (freeze?) PyTorch Lazy layers?

Tags: pytorch

PyTorch offers lazy layers e.g. `torch.nn.LazyLinear`. I want to freeze some of these layers in my network i.e. ensure they take no gradient steps. When I try `.requires_grad_(False)`, I receive the error:

`ValueError: Attempted to use an uninitialized parameter in <method 'requires_grad_' of 'torch._C._TensorBase' objects>. This error happens when you are using a` LazyModule`or explicitly manipulating`torch.nn.parameter.UninitializedParameter`objects. When using LazyModules Call`forward `with a dummy batch to initialize the parameters before calling torch functions`

How do I freeze lazy layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests you need to perform a dummy inference on a lazy module in order to fully initialize all of its parameters.

In other words, considering your correct input shape `shape`:

```
>>> model(torch.rand(shape))
```

And only then can you freeze the desired layer with `requires_grad_(False)`.